# YouTube Player API list with videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube Player API.

I want to make my own custom playlist directly in my code (not to use playlist ID from youtube)

Here is my playlist code which doesn't work

```
player.loadPlaylist({
    list:['mGalEx6ufUw', 'TaCUBtzKAnA', '4v8SPz4VfsU'], 
    listType: 'playlist', 
    index:0, 
    startSeconds:0, 
    suggestedQuality:'medium'
});
```

As the documentation says I can pass playlist ID or array with video IDs to parameter **list**, but it's not working.

If I write playlist ID instead of the array with video IDs it works.

Comment: No errors. I just don't get any videos playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer for this problem with the help of Jeffrey Posnick in [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/f1dd17b09c10f5dc).

You can make this working with the argument syntax instead of object syntax. More info [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)

Comment: still doesn't work for me https://jsfiddle.net/t14x6sLw/21/

Answer (score 8):

I solved this.

I think the API documentation seems to be wrong.
playlist ID and video IDs in loadPlaylist function should be used in a different way.

```
    function loadPlaylist_playlist_id() {
        player.loadPlaylist({
            'list': 'UUPW9TMt0le6orPKdDwLR93w',
            'listType': 'playlist',
            'index': 0,
            'startSeconds': 0,
            'suggestedQuality': 'small'
        });
    }
    function loadPlaylist_video_ids() {
        player.loadPlaylist({
            'playlist': ['9HPiBJBCOq8', 'Mp4D0oHEnjc', '8y1D8KGtHfQ', 'jEEF_50sBrI'],
            'listType': 'playlist',
            'index': 0,
            'startSeconds': 0,
            'suggestedQuality': 'small'
        });
    }
```

http://1004lucifer.blogspot.kr/2015/04/youtube-loadplaylist-function-issues-of.html

Comment: Explaining your answer in few words would be more helpful to the users.

Comment: doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048601/youtube-player-api-for-list-does-always-play-initial-video